# WP8 How to animate a ListBox with Blend

Tags: windows-phone-8, blend

I wonder how do an animation with listbox so that the first item comes first than the second, then the third, and so when the listbox is loading as in the example below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the TurnstileFeatherEffect from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com). Here is a [complete sample page](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PhoneToolkitSample/Samples/TurnstileFeatherEffectSample1.xaml).

You accomplish this by adding the following transitions to your page

```
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

And then state in which order you want them to fly in. You do this by setting the FeatheringIndex on each item that you want animated. If you have a ListBox that you want to animate the items, you only need to set the index on the ListBox itself and not on the DataTemplate.

```
<ListBox toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0">
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Added all without problems on my page and in my listbox toolkit: TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex = "0" plus nothing happens, just without any effect

Comment: You need to change the RootFrame of the application. In App.xaml.cs change the RootFrame assignment to RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();

Comment: I did that, but the first page does not get excited when the lists loads, only when I leave the page. I am loading it via trigger onload.

Comment: @famadori have you managed to solve that problem? my transitions only work when leaving the page as well.

Comment: So it's the first page of your app (eg: MainPage)? Is the info available when the page loads, or do you have to load the data?